# How to extend css without overriding the base css template (Python-Flask)

Tags: html, css, flask

I currently have a project folder as shown:

PROJECT

- static

  - base.css
  - login.css
- templates

  - base.html
  - login.html

I would like login.html to extend base.css (which I have figured out how to do it) but my problem is how to link login.css to this html file without it overriding base.css.

Comment: Why not combine the 2 css files into 1, and use unique id's in your html to refer to specific css?

Comment: I wanted to include a template that was pre-designed but I've found the solution and I've marked it. Thank you for your response as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to override your base.css you can add the login.css in html file first followed by your base.css. This way your base.css will never get override by login.css.

Comment: Oh wow! I was adding base.css first then login.css. I didn't know alignment also mattered. Thank you very much.